# Undefined control sequence but everything is defined

Tags: debugging, bugs

Minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,varwidth,xstring,environ}

\newsavebox{\tempbox} %Allows to use fbox in newenvironment

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{result}[1][\textwidth]{%
    \StrPosition{\BODY}{\qedhere}[\@Position]%
    \IfEq{\@Position}{0}{%
 
            \BODY
        
    }{%
        %% Does contain \qedhere
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{result}[7cm]
         abc $\mathcal{A}$
    \end{result}
\end{document}
```

The code above doesn't work for an unknown reason. Enven stranger is that if I use my original code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,varwidth,xstring,environ}

\newsavebox{\tempbox} %Allows to use fbox in newenvironment

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{result}[1][\textwidth]{%
    \StrPosition{\BODY}{\qedhere}[\@Position]%
    \IfEq{\@Position}{0}{%
        %% Does not contain \qedhere
        \begin{center} %The box will be centered
        \begin{lrbox}{\tempbox} %Allows to use fbox in newenvironment
        \begin{varwidth}{#1} %Minipage that set its width to the text width it contains
        \begin{center} 
            \BODY
        \end{center}
        \end{varwidth}
        \end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\tempbox}}
        \end{center}
    }{%
       
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}


    % \begin{result}[7cm]
    %      abc $\mathcal{A}$
    % \end{result}
\end{document}
```

and if I test with the following code, it works :

```
\begin{result}[7cm]
     abc $\mapsto $
\end{result}

\begin{center}
\begin{lrbox}{\tempbox} 
\begin{varwidth}{7cm}
\begin{center} 
      abc $\mathcal{A}$
\end{center}
\end{varwidth}
\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\tempbox}}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as if xstring doesn't like the \mathcal. You could use the in-built LaTeX tools:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,varwidth}

\newsavebox{\tempbox} %Allows to use fbox in newenvironment

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{result}{O{\textwidth}+b}
 {
    \tl_if_in:nnTF {#2}{\qedhere}
     {}{#2}
 }{}%
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{result}[7cm]
          abc $\mathcal{A}$
\end{result}
\end{document}
```